# Saving data into Ignite Cluster is not distributed evenly

Tags: apache-spark, caching, distribution, ignite

I am working on a use-case to store the data in an in-memory database and enable it to BI for analytics.

My main objective is,

1. Cache data in Ignite, if the data is more than available heap size, spill the data into Disk.
2. Upsert the CDC changes to the existing tables.
3. Enable Ignite table via JDBC from BI for analytics.
4. Analytics BI should be refreshed within 2 to 3secs.

As a part of this exercise, I was trying to load History data(~700m rows, size is approx 87Gi) into Ignite using Spark.

I was able to integrate spark with ignite and successfully saved the dataframe into Ignite table. After loading 8M records, I have observed that the table partitions are not distributed evenly in the cluster . Also, the data size on the disk is more compared to the Source data size. Approx 8M records occupied 20Gi space on disk. I tried all configuration settings but did not succeed to distribute the data evenly in cluster and compressed the data file on desk. Can someone pls help me fix the configuration issue? Did I miss any Ignite & Spark configuration to distribute the data evenly? Also how to check how much data is cached?

Please let me know if I need to provide more information.

Ignite Table

```
CREATE TABLE edw_dds_ticket (
    ..
    ..
    PRIMARY KEY (helix_uuid, ticket_issue_date)
) WITH "TEMPLATE=PARTITIONED,backups=1,affinity_key=ticket_issue_date";
```

node-configuration.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <property name="workDirectory" value="/mnt/ignite/work"/>
            <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                    <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                            <property name="checkpointPageBufferSize" value="#{2048L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                            <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
                            <!-- Custom region name. -->
                            <property name="name" value="500MB_Region"/>
                            <!-- 100 MB initial size. -->
                            <property name="initialSize" value="#{100L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                            <!-- 500 MB maximum size. -->
                            <property name="maxSize" value="#{500L * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="writeThrottlingEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="storagePath" value="/mnt/ignite/data"/>
                    <property name="walPath" value="/mnt/ignite/wal"/>
                    <!-- Disabling wal archive set same path as wal-->
                    <property name="walArchivePath" value="/mnt/ignite/wal"/>
                    <!--<property name="walArchivePath" value="/mnt/ignite/walarchive"/>-->
                    <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{256 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                    <property name="walCompactionEnabled" value="true"/>
                    <property name="pageSize" value="#{8 * 1024}"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration">
                                    <property name="namespace" value="ignite" />
                                    <property name="serviceName" value="ignite-service" />
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

statefulset.yaml

```yaml
# An example of a Kubernetes configuration for pod deployment.
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  # Cluster name.
  name: ignite-cluster
  namespace: ignite
spec:
  # The initial number of pods to be started by Kubernetes.
  replicas: 6
  serviceName: ignite
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ignite
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ignite
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: ignite
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60000
      containers:
        # Custom pod name.
      - name: ignite-node
        image: apacheignite/ignite:2.13.0
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "40Gi"
            cpu: "1"
          limits:
            memory: "40Gi"
            cpu: "4"
        env:
        - name: OPTION_LIBS
          value: ignite-kubernetes,ignite-rest-http,ignite-compress,ignite-spark-2.4,ignite-spring,ignite-indexing,ignite-log4j2,ignite-slf4j
        - name: CONFIG_URI
          value: file:///mnt/ignite/config/node-configuration.xml
        - name: JVM_OPTS
          value: "-server -Xms30g -Xmx30g -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G -DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true "
        - name: CONTROL_JVM_OPTS
          value: "-server -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Xms30g -Xmx30g -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+ScavengeBeforeFullGC -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2G  -DIGNITE_WAIT_FOR_BACKUPS_ON_SHUTDOWN=true"
        ports:
        # Ports to open.
        - containerPort: 47100 # communication SPI port
        - containerPort: 47500 # discovery SPI port
        - containerPort: 49112 # JMX port
        - containerPort: 10800 # thin clients/JDBC driver port
        - containerPort: 8080 # REST API
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /mnt/ignite/config
          name: config-vol
        - mountPath: /mnt/ignite/data
          name: data-vol
        - mountPath: /mnt/ignite/wal
          name: wal-vol
        - mountPath: /mnt/ignite/work
          name: work-vol
      securityContext:
        fsGroup: 2000 # try removing this if you have permission issues
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - weight: 1
            preference:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: agentpool
                operator: In
                values:
                - userpool1
      volumes:
      - name: config-vol
        configMap:
          name: ignite-configmap-with-persistence
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data-vol
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "managed-csi-premium"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "100Gi" 
  - metadata:
      name: work-vol
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "managed-csi-premium"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "10Gi" # make sure to provide enought space for your application data
  - metadata:
      name: wal-vol
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "managed-csi-premium"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: "5Gi"
#  - metadata:
#      name: walarchive-vol
#    spec:
#      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
#      storageClassName: "managed-csi-premium"
#      resources:
#        requests:
#          storage: "5Gi"
```

Spark Client Connection configuration.
spark-ignite-configmap.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: ignite-configmap
  namespace: spark
data:
  ignite-config.xml: |
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
        <!-- Imports default Ignite configuration -->
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
            <!--<property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/> -->
            <property name="clientMode" value="true"/>
            <property name="discoverySpi">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                    <property name="ipFinder">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.kubernetes.configuration.KubernetesConnectionConfiguration">
                                    <property name="namespace" value="ignite" />
                                    <property name="serviceName" value="ignite-service" />
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

spark.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: "sparkoperator.k8s.io/v1beta2"
kind: SparkApplication
metadata:
  name: spark-ignite
  namespace: spark
  labels:
    app: spark
spec:
  type: Scala
  mode: cluster
  image: "spark:v2.4.7_ignite"
  imagePullSecrets:
    - image-pull-secret
  imagePullPolicy: Always 
  mainClass: sparkentryclass
  arguments:
    - "2017-01-01"
    - "/ignite/config/ignite-config.xml"
  mainApplicationFile: "local:///opt/spark/examples/jars/IgnieDataFrame-1.0-SNAPSHOT-uber.jar"
  sparkVersion: "2.4.7"
  volumes:
    - name: config-vol
      configMap:
        name: ignite-configmap
  restartPolicy:
    type: Never
  driver:
    cores: 1
    memory: "10g"
    labels:
      version: 2.4.7
    serviceAccount: spark
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-vol
        mountPath: /ignite/config
  executor:
    cores: 3 
    instances: 5
    memory: "10g"
    labels:
      version: 2.4.7
    volumeMounts:
      - name: config-vol
        mountPath: /ignite/config
```

Spark Log: It clearly says 6 clusters(Ignite) and 6 clients(Spark Executors).
^-- Cluster [hosts=12, CPUs=55, servers=6, clients=6, topVer=14, minorTopVer=0]
^-- Network [addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.14.10], discoPort=0,

```
22/06/20 11:38:53 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 92.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 94) in 337817 ms on 192.168.14.14 (executor 3) (96/124)
22/06/20 11:39:13 INFO IgniteKernal:
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=ec62778c, uptime=00:19:00.103]
    ^-- Cluster [hosts=12, CPUs=55, servers=6, clients=6, topVer=14, minorTopVer=0]
    ^-- Network [addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.14.10], discoPort=0, commPort=47100]
    ^-- CPU [CPUs=16, curLoad=0.07%, avgLoad=0.12%, GC=0%]
    ^-- Heap [used=359MB, free=96.05%, comm=790MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=1, qSize=0]
    ^-- Striped thread pool [active=0, idle=16, qSize=0]
22/06/20 11:39:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 111.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 113, 192.168.14.12, executor 2, partition 111, PROCESS_LOCAL, 38281 bytes)
22/06/20 11:39:56 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 104.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 106) in 287029 ms on 192.168.14.12 (executor 2) (97/124)
22/06/20 11:40:01 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 112.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 114, 192.168.14.14, executor 3, partition 112, PROCESS_LOCAL, 35435 bytes)
22/06/20 11:40:01 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 94.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 96) in 354149 ms on 192.168.14.14 (executor 3) (98/124)
22/06/20 11:40:13 INFO IgniteKernal:
Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=ec62778c, uptime=00:20:00.110]
    ^-- Cluster [hosts=12, CPUs=55, servers=6, clients=6, topVer=14, minorTopVer=0]
    ^-- Network [addrs=[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1%lo, 127.0.0.1, 192.168.14.10], discoPort=0, commPort=47100]
    ^-- CPU [CPUs=16, curLoad=0.03%, avgLoad=0.12%, GC=0%]
    ^-- Heap [used=369MB, free=95.94%, comm=790MB]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=0, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=1, qSize=0]
    ^-- Striped thread pool [active=0, idle=16, qSize=0]
```

Ignite Cluster Pods Storage Details

```
Pod-5: k exec -it ignite-cluster-5 -- du -h /mnt/ignite/data
16.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/lost+found
340.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-3d2f2427-89f9-4950-b9ce-668864d79493/metastorage
104.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-3d2f2427-89f9-4950-b9ce-668864d79493/cache-SQL_PUBLIC_EDW_DDS_TICKET
88.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-3d2f2427-89f9-4950-b9ce-668864d79493/cp
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-3d2f2427-89f9-4950-b9ce-668864d79493/snp
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-3d2f2427-89f9-4950-b9ce-668864d79493/TxLog
60.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-3d2f2427-89f9-4950-b9ce-668864d79493/cache-ignite-sys-cache
608.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-3d2f2427-89f9-4950-b9ce-668864d79493
632.0K  /mnt/ignite/data
 
Pod-4: k exec -it ignite-cluster-4 -- du -h /mnt/ignite/data
16.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/lost+found
60.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-4f28bdd5-bd15-484f-860c-fcfa665c63f1/cache-ignite-sys-cache
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-4f28bdd5-bd15-484f-860c-fcfa665c63f1/snp
104.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-4f28bdd5-bd15-484f-860c-fcfa665c63f1/cache-SQL_PUBLIC_EDW_DDS_TICKET
324.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-4f28bdd5-bd15-484f-860c-fcfa665c63f1/metastorage
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-4f28bdd5-bd15-484f-860c-fcfa665c63f1/TxLog
72.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-4f28bdd5-bd15-484f-860c-fcfa665c63f1/cp
576.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-4f28bdd5-bd15-484f-860c-fcfa665c63f1
600.0K  /mnt/ignite/data
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Pod-3: k exec -it ignite-cluster-3 -- du -h /mnt/ignite/data
16.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/lost+found
24.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-1ec48b28-64c0-4dde-9690-2fea32cfb1f5/cp
316.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-1ec48b28-64c0-4dde-9690-2fea32cfb1f5/metastorage
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-1ec48b28-64c0-4dde-9690-2fea32cfb1f5/TxLog
18.4G   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-1ec48b28-64c0-4dde-9690-2fea32cfb1f5/cache-SQL_PUBLIC_EDW_DDS_TICKET
60.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-1ec48b28-64c0-4dde-9690-2fea32cfb1f5/cache-ignite-sys-cache
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-1ec48b28-64c0-4dde-9690-2fea32cfb1f5/snp
18.4G   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-1ec48b28-64c0-4dde-9690-2fea32cfb1f5
18.4G   /mnt/ignite/data
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Pod-2: k exec -it ignite-cluster-2 -- du -h /mnt/ignite/data
16.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/lost+found
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-56ad3ba2-6d57-4405-bee9-5e155d2dffd4/snp
308.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-56ad3ba2-6d57-4405-bee9-5e155d2dffd4/metastorage
24.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-56ad3ba2-6d57-4405-bee9-5e155d2dffd4/cp
20.7G   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-56ad3ba2-6d57-4405-bee9-5e155d2dffd4/cache-SQL_PUBLIC_EDW_DDS_TICKET
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-56ad3ba2-6d57-4405-bee9-5e155d2dffd4/TxLog
60.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-56ad3ba2-6d57-4405-bee9-5e155d2dffd4/cache-ignite-sys-cache
20.7G   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-56ad3ba2-6d57-4405-bee9-5e155d2dffd4
20.7G   /mnt/ignite/data
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Pod-1: k exec -it ignite-cluster-1 -- du -h /mnt/ignite/data
60.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-b30da2e8-4af9-492b-b15c-3371f5871508/cache-ignite-sys-cache
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-b30da2e8-4af9-492b-b15c-3371f5871508/TxLog
308.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-b30da2e8-4af9-492b-b15c-3371f5871508/metastorage
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-b30da2e8-4af9-492b-b15c-3371f5871508/snp
28.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-b30da2e8-4af9-492b-b15c-3371f5871508/cp
2.1G    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-b30da2e8-4af9-492b-b15c-3371f5871508/cache-SQL_PUBLIC_EDW_DDS_TICKET
2.1G    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-b30da2e8-4af9-492b-b15c-3371f5871508
16.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/lost+found
2.1G    /mnt/ignite/data
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Pod-1: k exec -it ignite-cluster-0 -- du -h /mnt/ignite/data
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-a1fbb947-6c8f-44ac-bb2c-7980f2316bb8/TxLog
324.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-a1fbb947-6c8f-44ac-bb2c-7980f2316bb8/metastorage
60.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-a1fbb947-6c8f-44ac-bb2c-7980f2316bb8/cache-ignite-sys-cache
4.0K    /mnt/ignite/data/node00-a1fbb947-6c8f-44ac-bb2c-7980f2316bb8/snp
104.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-a1fbb947-6c8f-44ac-bb2c-7980f2316bb8/cache-SQL_PUBLIC_EDW_DDS_TICKET
88.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/node00-a1fbb947-6c8f-44ac-bb2c-7980f2316bb8/cp
592.0K  /mnt/ignite/data/node00-a1fbb947-6c8f-44ac-bb2c-7980f2316bb8
16.0K   /mnt/ignite/data/lost+found
616.0K  /mnt/ignite/data
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a date as the affinity key tends to be a bad choice for exactly the reason you've found. It's not possible to say what the "correct" affinity key is with the information you've provided (data modelling is hard), but I can say that if you don't specify one you'll get much better distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have tried another column that has 800 distinct values. I still see the same behavior.

Node0 &1: 
```
[15:58:38]     ^-- Off-heap memory [used=6839MB, free=56.6%, allocated=15560MB]
[15:58:38]     ^-- Page memory [pages=870359]
[15:58:38]     ^-- Ignite persistence [used=6799MB]
```
Node 2 to 6:
```
[15:57:11]     ^-- Off-heap memory [used=0MB, free=100%, allocated=15560MB]
[15:57:11]     ^-- Page memory [pages=28]
[15:57:11]     ^-- Ignite persistence [used=0MB]
```

Comment: Also I see weird behavior. Cluster is crashing frequently when I am loading the data from spark to Ignite.

Comment: 800 distinct values isn’t enough to get really good distribution. “For an optimal distribution of keys over partitions and partitions over nodes, the following rule should be satisfied: The number of partitions should be significantly greater than the number of nodes, and the number of keys should be significantly greater than the number of partitions.” ([Source](https://www.gridgain.com/resources/blog/data-distribution-in-apache-ignite)]

Comment: Affinity function configuration in Apache Ignite
In the current implementation, the affinity function is a parameter of cache configuration.
Upon instantiation, the affinity function takes the following arguments:

1. Number of partitions
2. Number of backups (essentially, this argument is also a cache-configuration parameter)
3. Backup filter
4. Flag excludeNeighbors

If I understood correctly, we have to set the number of partitions to affinity function and the pass it to cacheConfiguraton. It is very hard to find the xml configuration. Can you pls provide the sample configuration?

Comment: Sorry for more comments. I see the default value is 1024. public RendezvousAffinityFunction(boolean exclNeighbors) {
        this(exclNeighbors, DFLT_PARTITION_COUNT);
    } which means in my case the values are 8M uuids > 1024 > 800(distinct affinity keys). Not sure why the data is still stored in one node? Is there any difference in persistence mode? When I load the data pure memory-based, it is distributed evenly.

Comment: How did you activate your cluster? I bet you only have the one node in your baseline topology. Use `control.sh —baseline` to see the current config and `control.sh —baseline add XXX` to add the missing nodes.

Comment: I see all nodes are added to baseline. Is there something wrong with auto adjustment? 

Command [BASELINE] started
Arguments: --baseline
-----------------------
Cluster state: active
Current topology version: 6
Baseline auto adjustment disabled: softTimeout=300000
Current topology version: 6 (Coordinator: ConsistentId=cf6a7dc5-eddb-4538-9346-6642122d9166, Address=ignite-cluster-0.ignite.ignite.svc.cluster.local/192.168.2.27, Order=1)

Baseline nodes: XXXXXXXXX
..................
Number of baseline nodes: 6

Other nodes not found.
Command [BASELINE] finished with code: 0

Comment: Thank you so much Stephen, now the data is distributed after enabling the auto adjustment.

Comment: I have one more query. When I try to copy data to Ignite using Spark. I see the below warnings. It is taking more time to copy the data.. 

 Possible failure suppressed accordingly to a configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=UnmodifiableSet [SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CR
ITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=data-streamer-stripe-7, igniteInstanceName=null, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1656065103283]]]